# Unity Sign in with Apple Refresh Token

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, oauth, apple-sign-in

I'm working on an iOS app in Unity 2019.4.

Is there a way to get a refresh token when using [Sign in with apple Unity's asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sign-in-with-apple-154202?_ga=2.236665665.1171289423.1591714283-1178953364.1590749113) as to avoid a user having to sign in everytime the user opens the app?

Storing the userID (email=SignInWithApple.CallbackArgs.userInfo.userId) that signed up in a prior session doesn't return credentialstate=Authorized in function SignInWithAppleTest.cs GetCredentialState (but null) - it only returns Authorized for the session the user is loging into:

```
var siwa = gameObject.GetComponent<SignInWithApple>();
    siwa.GetCredentialState(thisUSer, OnCredentialState);
```

I could only find this reference from [January2020](https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity/issues/3) of a similar asset to Unity's that said we could not get a refresh token.

Would you suggest I need to implement the process end-to-end with [REST API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)?

Cheers, Sergio